# jQuery replacing letters with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pulling some text from a database and I have `,` and I would like to replace them with `<br>` don't really know why it's not working any ideas?

JS Code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //.MoreInfoText
    var $infotext = $('.MoreInfoText').text().replace(/\+/g, '<br>');
    $.each($infotext, function() {
        $('.MoreInfoText').text($infotext);
    });
});
```

Text as its coming from the DB:
Ryan open 30/01/1998, ryan added numberOFIteams of NameOFIteams

Comment: do you have a sample of your html?

Comment: Use $('.MoreInfoText').text().replace(',', '');

Comment: because your replace is replacing `+` instead of `,`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st use `replace(/\,/g, '<br>'));` yours only replace `+`
(note the `g` means replace all, you can also make the search case-insensitive pass the "i" parameter ex: `/gi`)

2nd use `$('.MoreInfoText').html()` so your `<br>` are treated as **HTML** instead of string.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //.MoreInfoText
    $('.MoreInfoText').html($('.MoreInfoText').text().replace(/\,/g, '<br>'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="MoreInfoText">11111,22222,33333,44444,55555</span>
```

Comment: @RyanJ happy to help

Answer (score 3):

It should be `.replace(/,/g,"<br>")` so all `,`s get replaced with `<br>`. Right now it's replacing `+` with `<br>`.

Also to iterate over every element with class `MoreInfoText` replacing `,` with `<br>` modify your code like this:

```
        $('.MoreInfoText').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/,/g, '<br>')
            $(this).html(text);
        });
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with that ?
Error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in Ryan open 30/01/1998<br> ryan added numberOFIteams of NameOFIteamsRyan open 30/01/1998<br> ryan added numberOFIteams of NameOFIteams`

Code
`$( document ).ready(function() {
    //.MoreInfoText
    var $infotext = $('.MoreInfoText').text().replace(/,/g,"<br>");
    $.each($infotext, function() {
        $('.MoreInfoText').text($infotext);
    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //.MoreInfoText
    var $infotext = $('.MoreInfoText').text().replace(',', ' ');
    $.each($infotext, function() {
        $('.MoreInfoText').text($infotext);
    });
});
```

Comment: Will only replace one occurrence without the `/g` modifier

Comment: I'm getting a error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in Ryan open 30/01/1998  ryan added numberOFIteams of NameOFIteamsRyan open 30/01/1998, ryan added numberOFIteams of NameOFIteams`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend avoiding the usage of `<br />` for adding line breaks, you may consider using `<p>` instead.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //.MoreInfoText
    $('.MoreInfoText').each(function() {
        var moreArray = $(this).text().split(',');
        var $infotext = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < moreArray.length; i++){
            $infotext += '<p>' + moreArray[i] + '</p>';
        }
        $(this).empty().html($infotext);
    });
});
```

If paragraphs are not already placed each on a new line, you can add a CSS rule for that. This helps separating the content from the presentation, which is what CSS is for.

Comment: I'm getting an error with that ?
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in <p>0</p><p>1</p><p>2</p>`